# mongodb one to many relationship using nodejs and express

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

Its been a tough time for me trying to figure this out.
The problem I'm trying to solve is this:
I have USERS who has list of COMPANIES,
this COMPNAY has list of PROJECTS etc.

I'm trying to create a PROJECT under a COMPANY and a COMPANY under a USER using referencing.
This USER is going to be populated from form fields likewise COMPANY PROJECT

USERS SCHEMA

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema  = mongoose.Schema;

//============= User Schema============//
const userSchema = new Schema({
name: String,
email: String,

//referencing user's company/companies
company: [
    {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, 
        ref: 'company',
    },
],  
},{
timestamps: true
});

const Users = mongoose.model('user', userSchema);
module.exports = Users;
```

COMPANY SCHEMA

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema  = mongoose.Schema;

//======== Company schema ========//
const compSchema = new Schema({
company_name: String,

//referencing user schema
user: [
  {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'user',
  },
],

//referencing projects
projects: [
    {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, 
      ref: 'project',
    },
  ],
},{
  timestamps: true
});

const Company = mongoose.model('company', compSchema);
module.exports = Company;
```

PROJECT SCHEMA

```
 const mongoose = require('mongoose');
 const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

//PROJECT SCHEMA
 const projectSchema = new Schema({
 project_title: String,
 
 //referencing company schema
 company: [
   {
     type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
     ref: 'company',
   }
 ],
},{
timestamps: true
});

const Projects = mongoose.model('project', projectSchema);
module.exports = Projects;
```

CONTROLLERS

```
 const Users = require('./userSchema');
 const Company = require('./companySchema');
 const Projects = require('./projectSchema');

 //create user
exports.createUser = async (req, res) => {
  const data = {
   name: req.body.name,
   email: req.body.email,
  }
  Users.create(data, (err, done) => {
    if(err) return err;
    res.json({UserData: done});
    return;
  });
}
exports.getAllUsers = async(req, res) => {
}

 //create company
exports.createCompany = async (req, res) => {
   const CompanyData = {
   company_name: req.body.company_name,
  }
  Company.create(companyData, (err, done) => {
    if(err) return err;
    res.json({CompanyDetails: done});
    return;
  });
}
exports.getllCompany = async (req, res) => {
}

//create project
exports.createProject = async (req, res) => {
  const projectData = {
   project_title: req.body.project_title,
  }
  Projects.create(projectData, (err, done) => {
    if(err) return err;
    res.json({ProjectDetails: done});
    return;
  });
}
exports.getAllProjects = async (req, res) => {
}
```

I understand that populate can be used to push documents to children. Any assistance offered will be highly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Store reference

Firstly, while creating a `Company` inside `createCompany` controller, you should add user `_id` in `users` array like this:

```js
const CompanyData = {
    company_name: req.body.company_name,
    users: [req.body.userId]    // Lets assume, user _id is coming in request body
  }
  Company.create(companyData, (err, done) => {
    // Your code
  });
```

Then, when you create a `Project`, add _id of `Company` you just created, in `createProject` controller like this:

```js
const projectData = {
    project_title: req.body.project_title,
    company: [req.body.comapnyId]   // Again assuming, company _id is coming in request body
  }
  Projects.create(projectData, (err, done) => {
    // Your code
  });
```

## Update reference

Also, as I see in your schemas, you are trying to keep it bidirectional, like user's _ids in company doc & company's _ids in user doc.
To achieve this, if you create a user, you should update the corresponding company with pushing(`addToSet` actually) new user _id in `user` array.

Example:

To create a user in controller, run two scripts synchronously one-by-one:

1. Create a user with company _id and other details.

```js
const data = {
   name: req.body.name,
   email: req.body.email,
   company: [req.body.companyId]
  }
  Users.create(data, (err, done) => {
    // Your code
  });
```

2. Update company doc(whose _id is saved in above user) with _id of newly created user.

```js
const updateCompany = { "$addToSet": { user: user._id } };   // Get `user._id` from above synchronous script
   
  Company.update({_id: req.body.companyId}, data, (err, done) => {  // Updated filter
    // Your code
  });
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer @rahul. But I thought I'm supposed to pass `updateCompany` like so `Company.update(updateCompany(err, done))`?. Well, I did it this way but got a `ReferenceError: user is not defined`. Please kindly assist. Thanks

Comment: You need to run the above two tasks one by one. First, create a user and then take user _id and pass into `companyUpdate` object. You can run one by one using [async.waterfall method](https://caolan.github.io/async/v3/docs.html#waterfall)

Comment: I did a mistake that I didn't add a filter while updating the doc. I have updated the `Company.update` with first arg as filter object `{_id: req.body.companyId}`

Comment: I've tried all that you suggested except for the [async-waterfall-method]. But I was getting the array of company in Users document and an array of user in Company document each set to 0 null. But I'm still getting the error mentioned above. I want to also mention that I haven't done this before, any further assistance will be highly appreciated. Thanks @rahul.

Comment: Error is coming bec you have created `user` but not passed it to the next stage which is updating company. Refer to this [example](https://github.com/Rahul-Geeks/trello/blob/b061c36d13e09dc1a8cbe0a11a322580013ca0e2/app/routes/cards.js#L11) where I am first creating a card and the updating list with card details same as your situation